# Remove the top border on TabView?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Is there any way to remove the top border of a TabView on iOS?

[image: Tab view]

I've tried adding `border-width: 0;` and `border-color: transparent;` to the `TabView` but neither of these seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `clipsToBounds` to `true` on `UITabBar`.

**HTML**

```
<TabView (loaded)="onTabViewLoaded($event)">
```

**TS**

```
   onTabViewLoaded(event) {
        if (event.object.ios) {
            event.object.viewController.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That does remove the border, but it also removes the background color - is there a way to add that back in?

Comment: Updated the answer, `clipsToBounds` hides just the border and doesn't affect the background color.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!